# First order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for help to solve the following equation.  The $y^2$ term is really confusing me. I suspect I need a substitution but cannot think what...

$$x^2 y' = 1 - x^2 + y^2 -x^2 y^2$$

Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to format equations and math expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints;

1)It's separable, after some algebraic manipulation you get $$y'=\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-1\right )(y^2+1)$$
2)$$\int \frac{y'}{y^2+1} dx=\tan^{-1}(y)+c$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Nice and concise :) I made the $\tan$ a proper function (`\tan`) for better reading. (+1)

Comment: @AlexR Oh, I do that too, don't know why I forgot it this time. Thanks.